# Python IDLE debugger bypasses the breakpoint set?

Tags: python, debugging, python-idle

When i set a breakpoint in a .py file in python IDLE , and rUn the debugger . The debugger bypasses the breakpoint and runs through the code without stopping at the breakpoint. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're doing? Without more info it could be . . . well, anything.

Comment: I recently fixed a bug that caused breakpoints to disappear when editing a file.  The fix will appear in future Idle releases.  The other user's answers may have been correct also.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that debug is enabled in IDLE by clicking on Debug -> Debugger on the menu bar. Break points are skipped if not in debug mode.

It's also possible that the execution path never gets to your breakpoint. If that's the case, you should place a breakpoint earlier in your script.